# How to iterate over query params in Golang

Tags: http, go, go-fiber

I am using Fiber package in Golang to handle the httprequests and want to find all the query params present in request

```
GET http://example.com/shoes?order=desc&brand=nike&lang=english
```

I want to iterate over query params and looking for something like this

```
for k, v := range c.AllQueries() {
    reqObj[k] = v[0]
}
```

Expected output:

```
"order" : "desc"
"brand" : "nike"
"lang" : "english"
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/master/ctx.go#L938) is the link of `AllParams` implementation. We can see this method returns a `map[string]string` of query params. So `AllParams` is what you need.

```golang
params := c.AllParams()
for k, v := range params {
    // do something with the values
}
```

Edit:
Go-fiber uses fasthttp under the hood. You can look into this [method](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/master/ctx.go#L1028) block and iterate the `fasthttp.QueryArgs()` the way they are doing.

```golang
c.fasthttp.QueryArgs().VisitAll(func(key, val []byte) {
   // implement what you want to do with the key values here
})
```

Comment: AllParams() gives me path variables (eq /:id) but I want to find all Query parameters (eq ?lang = english)

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think this will solve your issue!

Comment: Thank you. I thought the solution didnt exist for this as there was no method for this.